# Which machine learning or deep learning model to use / make

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, model-selection, data-mining, conv-neural-network

I wanted to use machine learning / deep learning to predict profit of a , say, a shop using satellite imagery and previous data and I don't know what to use. 
I want to use close satellite imagery to check how many shops are clustered in a region and of what type and predict their profit using previous data of regions having similar clustering . 
For example - if there are 10 Samsung shops in one sq km their profit would be less than 1 Samsung shop in one sq.km (in a popular area) surrounded by different shops as a customer wanting a Samsung product would be more likely to buy from that shop. Using previous data and satellite imagery I want to predict how much the shop would earn depending on its location and previous year profits and profits of shops having similar locations.
I don't know what exactly to use for this ( ML or DL, CNN or something else? , Which library ?) I wanna know how to go about this. I also want to know how the data could be mined
Thanking you in advance .

Answer (score 1):

For image processing, the natural choice of model is a convolutional neural network. CNNs are fairy straightforward to implement in Keras, which you can install for Python or R (which will use Python under the hood). There are tutorials online about how to implement CNNs. This one looks good: https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-convolutional-neural-network-cnn-in-keras-329fbbadc5f5.

I'll copy the most important code pieces here. This should give a feel for how to do it in Python.

```
#create model
model = Sequential()
#add model layers
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, activation=’relu’, input_shape=(28,28,1)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, activation=’relu’))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(10, activation=’softmax’))

#compile model using accuracy to measure model performance
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

#train the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=3)

#predict first 4 images in the test set
model.predict(X_test[:4])

#actual results for first 4 images in test set
y_test[:4]
```

The implementation in R will have different syntax, but it follows the same idea. This "sequential" model in Keras makes it pretty easy to tweak the neural network layers to your heart's content.